# Can I use an HTTPS connection for editing and posting on Blogger?

Tags: blogger, https

Is there a way to get an HTTPS connection when editing or posting on blogger?

Comment: I've just blogged about this http://gmailblog.blogspot.co.uk/2008/07/making-security-easier.html and in there I propose the idea of a cloud based service to allow the secure access to blogger. Anybody knows a good option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seem like Google does not enable HTTPS for more than the login process on Blogger. The main reason for this seems to be that using HTTPS is very resource intensive. See this [Google Blogger support tread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/blogger/thread?tid=3b52d974d24b5c5a&hl=en).

Comment: You're right, and I'm fascinated by Google's justification, considering my gmail is all SSL by default! And I'd imagine gmail gets much more frequent traffic than blogger.

Comment: @Kevin But there is generally a bigger demand for security with email than a blog.  Presumably what's edited on a blog most of the time is or will become public so the demand for https is much lower.

Comment: The link above doesn't work anymore (and I couldn't find that article in that blogger group)